# Latest Version of Gmail Contacts

Tags: gmail

I am trying to learn how to scroll down my list of Gmail contacts. Where does one learn how to do that? Where does one find Gmail's latest version of Gmail Contacts?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer here since I'm not sure this is what you're asking.

Gmail/Google contacts can be managed by either:

1. Going to [google.com/contacts](http://google.com/contacts)
2. Going to Gmail and clicking *Gmail* → *Contacts* at the left of the top toolbar.

Both ways will let you see which Gmail contacts you have, as well as let you manage contacts based on who you have in your Google+ circles.